# Number of pairs of permutation in $S_n$ whose $\mu$-coefficient (of their Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial) is non-zero

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, coxeter-groups, hecke-algebras, kazhdan-lusztig

I am interested in how many pairs of permutations $(u,w)$ in $S_n$, such that the $\mu$-coefficient of its Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomial $P_{u,w}(q)$ is non-zero? where $\mu_{u,w}=[q^{\frac{l(w)-l(u)-1}{2}}]P_{u,w}(q)$.

Let's call this number $M_n$.

I've computed for small $n$'s , but my results seem to be wrong:

$M_3=8$ $M_4=58$
$M_5=480$
$M_6=4238$

Are there any known properties about this?

Are there any known sufficient conditions for the $\mu$ coefficient to be non-zero (seems to be not)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I calculated these numbers using Marc van Leeuwen and Fokko du Cloux's software atlas, I got

- S_3: 8
- S_4: 60
- S_5: 482
- S_6: 4268
- S_7: 41934
- S_8: 457782

(I could easily have made some silly mistake in coding, but I checked the answers by hand in rank 2, and the fact that they're close to yours makes me believe these.) I did the calculations also for some other Weyl groups:

- BC_2: 12
- BC_3: 152
- BC_4: 2148
- BC_5: 35070
- BC_6: 679152
- D_4: 892
- D_5: 14874
- D_6: 287438
- G_2: 20
- F_4: 8920
- E_6: 846476

I don't know any simple answers to your questions. The most interesting results about mu are in the work of Greg Warrington and his collaborators; see for example

Warrington, Gregory S. Equivalence classes for the μ-coefficient of Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials in Sn. Exp. Math. 20 (2011), no. 4, 457–466.

Comment: I did a quick check using the old Chevie package for GAP, and I get the same numbers for those small ranks I actually checked (up to rank $4$ for others than $A$ which I checked up to $6$). I didn't check any more, as I did this very naively, so it would take too long, but this should indicate that there was no error in your code (and the OP has somehow missed a few pairs).

Comment: @W.Z There are a lot of pairs, so it might be impractical to write them here. But in type $A_3$ there just happens to be precisely 2 pairs with non-zero $\mu$-coefficient and which differ in length by more than $1$, so these are a likely candidate for the missing pairs. Explicitly they are $(s_2,s_2s_1s_3s_2)$ and $(s_1s_3,s_1s_2s_3s_2s_1)$.

Comment: would you mind adding this to http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/NewStatistic, ideally with your code? (any package will do, several implementations even better, sage is ideal)

Comment: This is now http://findstat.org/St001143